# Array has no value after being passed ByRef to sub

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a module in a worksheet that is supposed to pass an array to another sub in the same module. So far, I've noticed that the variable N which is being used to to pull each individual array element always says 0 in the watch window, how do I get my elements out of the array? Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateReports()

Dim numRows As Integer
Dim numCount As Integer
Dim category As String
Dim size As Integer
Dim sizeCount As Integer

Dim departmentNums() As Integer
With Sheets("GM Alignment")
    numRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:A1048576"))
    .Range("A2").Select
    Do While numCount < numRows
        category = ActiveCell.Value
        size = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count - 1
        If size > 7 Then
            size = 0
        End If
        ReDim departmentNums(size)
        .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
        For sizeCount = 0 To size
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            departmentNums(sizeCount) = ActiveCell.Value
        Next sizeCount
        .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
        GenerateReports Arr:=departmentNums, Sheet:=category
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    numCount = numCount + 1
    Loop
End With

End Sub

Sub GenerateReports(ByRef Arr() As Integer, Sheet As String)

Dim N As Integer

For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)

    Dim Lastrow As Long

    With Sheets("DATA")

        If .Range("I:I").Find(N, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No " + Sheet + " rows found. ", , "No Rows Copied": Exit Sub
        Else

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            Lastrow = .Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("K1:K" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=N
            .Range("K2:K" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets(Sheet).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
            .AutoFilterMode = False

            'Position on cell A3
            With Application
                .CutCopyMode = False
                .Goto Sheets("DATA").Range("A2")
                .ScreenUpdating = True
            End With

            MsgBox "All matching data has been copied.", , "Copy Complete"

        End If

    End With

Next N

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the purpose of `If size > 7 Then size = 0`? If your columns are such that the if test is passed then that would cause the array to be of dimensions (0 to 0) (i.e. 1 element).

Comment: @Cor_Blimey its a wonky work around because I have to have this finished by tomorrow. Basically, some of the rows are only 1 column wide, and if I use `Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count - 1` on them then the size is up in the 16k. Which is wrong.

Comment: Do a debug.print on the array departmentNums before passing it to your next sub, see if it holds the value you're looking to pass.  It could be the code fails to capture the value into the array, instead of array having no value after passed byref

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line that calls GenerateReports (click in the margin - you should see a red dot). When the code reaches that you can look at your variables in the Locals window. Then step through execution (F8) and see what is happening.

Comment: At what point do you ever read from or write to `Arr` in `GenerateReports`?

Comment: @Alex it does contain the values I want to pass.

Comment: in that case then, you never use the values in it. N is 0 because of the size of the array. To **access** the data in the array (on your line `.Range("K1:K" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=N`) you need to use `Arr(N)`

Comment: @ptwales The line `For N = LBund(Arr) To UBound(Arr)`.

@Cor_Blimey I have done that, the problem is that the variable 'N' never equals anything.

Comment: what are you expecting it to equal? LBound(Arr) is 0 (because departmentNums was dimensioned as 0 to sizeCount) therefore N is 0 for the first loop

Comment: @Cor_Blimey that makes sense, but the size of the array for the first loop through should be 5, it always says 0. That's why I thought I may be passing the array incorrectly.

Comment: @JonathanGeorge If it does contains the value, try do the same thing in sub GenerateReports(), output say Arr(0), Arr(1) right after your dims.  I suggest you to put stopper (F9) when you test it.

Comment: "Size of the array for the first loop" Do you mean the size of Arr or Arr(0)?  What is `UBound(Arr)` in `GenerateReports()`?

Answer (score 0):

Not really looking too far into your code but I noticed that at no point do you read from or assign to `Arr` in `GenerateReports`.  I believe you are misunderstanding how Arrays behave.

```
Dim index as Integer
For index = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    Debug.Print "Index: "; index; " Value: " Arr(index)
Next N
```

`LBound(Arr)` and `Ubound(Arr)` return the lowest and highest index of `Arr` not the values.  In order to access the values contained in `Arr` use `Arr(index)`.

If you don't care about the index you can use

```
   Dim element as Integer
   For each element in Arr
      debug.Print element
   Next n
```

It is recommended to use this method whenever possible, as it allows for other sequence's to be used such as `Collection`.  However, it is not always possible such as when you are iterating over multiple sequences or parts of a sequence.

Here is a basic example:

```
Sub PrintOneToTen()
   Dim xs(1 to 10) as Integer
   FillArray xs
   Dim x as Integer
   For Each x In xs
       Debug.Print x
   Next x
   ' or just Debug.Print Join(xs, vbNewLine)
End Sub
Sub FillArray(ByRef xs() As Integer)
   Dim i as Integer
   For i = LBound(xs) To Ubound(xs)
       xs(i) = i
   Next i
End Sub
```

Documentation for VB.NET Arrays is listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx).  Note VB.NET is not VBA, but as far as arrays are concerned 99% of the info there should be the same in VBA.  I would post the VBA documentation but it's buried deep in Microsofts' database and I don't believe they care about it.